# Pygame Using shift when entering name

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard-events

I started using Pygame a month back and have my first game up and running fine with a high score table and player name entry box.  My problem is getting the shift key to work when the player enters their name.
Rather than mess up my game I created a small test program.  Whenever I hit any modifier key or the keypad I get an error "File "C:\PythonProjects\NameBox\namebox.py", line 61, in ask current_string += chr(inkey)
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)"

Could any one please help me get this working.  I've tried many suggestions I found on the web but can't get any of them to work.  Maybe there's a better way to do this but at least this gives me a name (all be it lower case only) and enters it along with the score and date into the high scores table in the correct place.

This is my test program.  Hope I entered the code correctly.

```
import pygame, sys, os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'  # centers Pygame SCREEN on desktop

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.font.init()

SCREENWIDTH = 640
SCREENHEIGHT = 480 
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH+9, SCREENHEIGHT+9))
BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18, bold = False, italic=False)
WHITE     = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK     = (  0,   0,   0)
GREEN     = (  0, 255,   0)
DARKGREEN = (  0, 128,   0)

def main():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_n:
                    getname()

        spaceSurf = BASICFONT.render('Press n to enter name', False, WHITE)
        spaceRect = spaceSurf.get_rect()
        spaceRect.midtop = (SCREENWIDTH / 2, SCREENHEIGHT - 30)
        SCREEN.blit(spaceSurf, spaceRect)
        pygame.display.update()

def getname():
    name = ask("Your name")
    SCREEN.fill(BLACK)
    nSurf = BASICFONT.render('Press n to enter name', False, WHITE)
    nRect = nSurf.get_rect()
    nRect.midtop = (SCREENWIDTH / 2, SCREENHEIGHT - 30)
    SCREEN.blit(nSurf, nRect)

    nameSurf = BASICFONT.render('Your name is '+ name, True, WHITE)
    nameRect = nameSurf.get_rect()
    nameRect.midtop = (SCREENWIDTH / 2, SCREENHEIGHT / 2)
    SCREEN.blit(nameSurf, nameRect)

    pygame.display.update()

def ask(question):
    "ask(question) -> answer"
    current_string = ""
    display_box(question + ": " + current_string)
    while 1:
        inkey = get_key()
        if inkey == K_BACKSPACE:
            current_string -= 1
        elif inkey == K_RETURN or inkey == K_KP_ENTER:
            break
        elif inkey == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            terminate()
        else:
            current_string += chr(inkey)

        display_box(question + ": " + current_string.capitalize())

    return current_string.capitalize() # this is the answer    

def get_key():
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                return event.key
            else:
                pass

def display_box(message):
  "Print a message in a box in the middle of the screen"
  SCREEN.fill(BLACK)
  left = (SCREENWIDTH / 2) - 156
  top = (SCREENHEIGHT / 2) -100
  pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, DARKGREEN, (left, top, 320, 200)) 
  SCREEN.blit(BASICFONT.render("New High Score!", True, GREEN),(left + 90, top + 35)) 
  SCREEN.blit(BASICFONT.render("Press Enter when done.", True, GREEN),
          (left + 51, top + 160)) 

  pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, BLACK, (left + 39, top + 110, 240, 20))
  pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, WHITE, (left + 38, top + 108, 244, 24), 1)

  if len(message) != 0:
      SCREEN.blit(BASICFONT.render(message, True, WHITE), (left+42, top + 111))

  pygame.display.update()

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** After reading more carefully [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2671589/520779) and [the docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html), I think I found a better way to accomplish what you want.

The `KEYDOWN` event has an additional attribute, `unicode`. Quoting the docs:

> The pygame.KEYDOWN event has an additional attributes unicode, and scancode. unicode represents a single character string that is the fully translated character entered. This takes into account the shift and composition keys. scancode represents the platform specific key code. This could be different from keyboard to keyboard, but is useful for key selection of weird keys like the multimedia keys.

I'd suggest returning not a value but a tuple from your `get_key`, so you have access to the two values:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    return (event.key, event.unicode)
```

In your calling code, instead of using `chr(inkey)` use the `unicode` value instead:

```
(inkey, unichr) = get_key()
...
else:
    current_string += unichr
```

This way the correct character will be appended to the string, with all the little details (modifier keys, dead keys etc) already dealt with.

P.S. Don't use `string.capitalize()` or it will mess with your string. Quoting [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize):

> Return a copy of the string with its first character capitalized and the rest lowercased.

That means any letters is your string will **always** follow this pattern: uppercase if it's the first character, lowercase otherwise. Other chars (that has no case) will be unchanged. Some examples:

```
>>> "aBcDeF".capitalize()
"Abcdef"
>>> "a123B".capitalize()
"A123b"
>>> "@#$%".capitalize()
"@#$%"
>>> "qq2@3#~`?/|\\".capitalize()
"Qq2@3#~`?/|\\"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  First try and I'm still getting the same ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256) when I hold the shift key.  Maybe not interpreting your answer correctly so will keep trying.

Comment: Make sure the code that calls `chr()` is **only** called inside the `elif` in the step 1, and the error should go away. BTW have you looked at the linked question? It really seems to be a better option. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yes I had tried the linked question which did give me caps with the shift key but couldn't get the backspace and returnkeys to work.

Comment: I had also read about unicode but couldn't find a simple example for a noob.  Your unicode solution works with the shift key, I now have caps but it doesn't like my code for the backspace and return keys.

Comment: Further testing and i got the backspace working with if inkey == K_BACKSPACE: current_string = current_string[:-1]  The rturn and escape keys work.  The only problem now is only the first char is capitalized even without the shift key.  None of the rest will capitalize.  I lost your code for the key up event that may fix it.

Comment: You can see my old answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10867552/revisions), but don't use it, the new one is a lot better. The first char is being capitalized because you're calling `current_string.capitalize()`, if you use the string as-is this problem won't happen.

Comment: Edit (Sorry I should have looked before posting.)  Found the key up event code again from a backup but it had no effect.  More testing and find that the shift key works with everything except A...Z.  All the @#$% etc keys work and the numpad works but not the letters.  Weird!!  This is a sample output alternating the shift key Qq2@3#~`?/|\  If the first char is a letter it is always capitalized with or without shift.

Comment: Ahhhh a simple left over tripped me up.  Now works perfectly, exactly what I wanted.  Thanks for your help and patience with a noob.  I'll post the final code so it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

This is my final working solution.  Hope it will help others.

```
" This demonstrates how to show an input box on screen and get the player name."
" By Barberic http://web.aanet.com.au/~barberic/"
" with thanks for help from mgibsonbr on stackoverflow.com"

import pygame, sys, os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'  # centers Pygame SCREEN on desktop

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.font.init()

SCREENWIDTH = 640
SCREENHEIGHT = 480 
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18, bold = False, italic=False)
WHITE     = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK     = (  0,   0,   0)
GREEN     = (  0, 255,   0)
DARKGREEN = (  0, 128,   0)

def main():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_n:
                    getname()

        spaceRect = spaceSurf.get_rect()
        spaceRect.midtop = (SCREENWIDTH / 2, SCREENHEIGHT - 30)
        SCREEN.blit(spaceSurf, spaceRect)
        pygame.display.update()

def getname():
    name = ask("Your name")
    SCREEN.fill(BLACK)
    nSurf = BASICFONT.render('Press n to enter name', False, WHITE)
    nRect = nSurf.get_rect()
    nRect.midtop = (SCREENWIDTH / 2, SCREENHEIGHT - 30)
    SCREEN.blit(nSurf, nRect)

    # display the name on screen
    nameSurf = BASICFONT.render('Your name is '+ name, True, WHITE)
    nameRect = nameSurf.get_rect()
    nameRect.midtop = (SCREENWIDTH / 2, SCREENHEIGHT / 2)
    SCREEN.blit(nameSurf, nameRect)

    pygame.display.update()

def ask(question):
    "ask(question) -> answer"
    current_string = ""
    display_box(question + ": " + current_string)
    while 1:
        (inkey, unichr) = get_key()

        if inkey == K_BACKSPACE:  # remove last char
            current_string = current_string[:-1]
        elif inkey == K_RETURN or inkey == K_KP_ENTER:
            break   # break out of the while loop to return current_string
        elif inkey == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            terminate()
        else:  
           current_string += unichr  # add a new char

        # limit the name length to 12 characters 
        current_string = current_string[:12]
        # show the current name during typing
        display_box(question + ": " + current_string)

    return current_string # this is the answer    

def get_key():
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                return (event.key, event.unicode)

def display_box(message):
  "Print a message in a box in the middle of the screen"
  SCREEN.fill(BLACK)
  left = (SCREENWIDTH / 2) - 156
  top = (SCREENHEIGHT / 2) -100
  pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, DARKGREEN, (left, top, 320, 200)) 
  SCREEN.blit(BASICFONT.render("New High Score!", True, GREEN),
              (left + 90, top + 35)) 
  SCREEN.blit(BASICFONT.render("Press Enter when done.", True, GREEN),
              (left + 51, top + 160)) 

  pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, BLACK, (left + 39, top + 110, 240, 20))
  pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, WHITE, (left + 38, top + 108, 244, 24), 1)

  if len(message) != 0:
    SCREEN.blit(BASICFONT.render(message, True, WHITE), (left+42, top + 111))

  pygame.display.update()

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```